# Does TCP retransmit require the program to still be running?

Tags: sockets, tcp

Does TCP retransmit depend on the client application being in a running state in order to resend a packet?  Or is that handled by the operating system?  I have a tiny program which when it runs, it sends some data and then exits immediately.  Does it need to wait for acknowledgement from the server?

Here's a simplified C# snippet to show what I'm talking about:

```
var socket = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
socket.Connect(host, port);
socket.NoDelay = true;
socket.GetStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
socket.GetStream().Flush();
Environment.Exit();
```

Will this retransmit if the packet gets lost, or does it have the same reliability as sending a UDP packet?

Comment: It does not need to wait. Both the send and the close are asynchronous, and for this purpose the socket will survive the process that created it.

Comment: I should have said the *connection* will survive the process that created it, as you will see with `netstat`.